# Uploadify not displaying browse button in FireFox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, uploadify

I have been having some issues with uploadify not displaying the Browse Button in FireFox.  It currently works in IE 9 and Chrome.  However, some users in IE 9 have reported that it doesn't work.  I am using the most current version of the uploadify library.  Has anyone else had this issue?  I am using C# in an ASP.NET web application.  I use a IHttpHandler in a ashx file to handle the upload.

Here is my code for the uploadify:

```
$(document).ready(
            function () {
                $("#<%=fuImage.ClientID %>").uploadify({
                    'swf': 'scripts/uploadify.swf',
                    'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
                    'uploader': 'Upload.ashx',
                    'folder': 'uploads',
                    'fileTypeDesc': 'Image Files',
                    'fileTypeExts': '*.jpg;*.jpeg',
                    'formData': { 'DocumentId': '<%=this.DocumentTypeID %>', 'CustomerId': '<%=Profile.DealerProfile.CurrentProfile.OnyxCompanyID == null ? 0 : Profile.DealerProfile.CurrentProfile.OnyxCompanyID.Value %>', 'LargeHeight': '<%=this.LargeHeight %>', 'LargeWidth': '<%=this.LargeWidth %>', 'ThumbnailHeight': '<%=this.ThumbnailHeight %>', 'ThumbnailWidth': '<%=this.ThumbnailWidth %>', 'ImageType': '1' },
                    'onQueueComplete': function () { setTimeout(function () { location.reload(true); }, 100); },
                    'multi': true,
                    'auto': true
                });}};
```

I noticed that the samples on the uploadify website didn't necessarily match up to the uploadify utility and I had to change parameter names.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: No, there are no errors showing.

Comment: How about in the network panel?  Do you have any connections failing?  Is it online?  If you can provide a link I can see if there are any such issues.

Comment: I can connect to it from outside the network and what is interesting is that I connected from outside the network with FF 27.0.1 from Windows 7 and it works fine.  I am running against it from inside the network with the same setup and it doesn't work.

Comment: Does it work in Chrome?

Comment: Yes, it works in Chrome.

Comment: If you aren't getting any errors in your Network panel in Chrome, and no javascript errors, then all I can suggest is just try creating a standalone app and see if it works.  If it works, then you know there is some incompatibility in your code + the uploadify code.  If it doesn't work, then Uploadify doesn't work in FF and you should contact support.

Comment: They don't have any way to contact support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browse button may not be displaying if Flash is not installed.  This solution requires Flash in order to work properly.